# How do I flatten an array in SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, select

I am trying to extract `custom_entry(s)` from the table `t_Open_Issues` and they are being returned as an Array.   They are user defined fields that can be created for andy departments issues.  Using SQL I am trying to find the code that will allow me to return them as part of a single table and have them not be an array inside the primary table.  I am looking for the SQL statement(s) that will allow me to flatten the array `custom_entry` and return `.entry_name` and `.entry.value` as unique columns in the table `t_Open_Issues`.

The SQL Statement below captures what I need, but the custom entries are returned as an array, instead of columns in `t_Open_Issues`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE.t_Open_Issues AS SELECT summary,
    custom_entry.entry_name,       
    custom_entry.value
    issue_num,
    status,
    createddate,
    modifieddate    
FROM t_Issue_Table
WHERE (
    custom_entry.entry_name = 'Audit Number:' OR    
    custom_entry.entry_name = 'Drawings attached:' OR
    custom_entry.entry_name = 'Checklist Complete:'
)
AND department_num = '123456'
AND (
    status = 'ASSIGNED' OR
    status = 'COMPLETE' OR
    status  = 'PROCESSED'
)
```

Comment: Your question would be much clearer with an example of the current result and an example the expected result.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: "*but the custom entries are returned as an array*" I don't see any array functions in that SQL statement